# Merge Sort на C. Неверная работа верного алгоритма

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка

В ходе написания алгоритма Merge Sort на языке C возникла проблема с выходными данными. Сам алгоритм описан верно, что уже многократно проверил, но выходные данные не соответствуют ожидаемому результату.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error(const unsigned uCode);
void get_array(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nLength);
void set_array(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nLength);
void merge(int nTargetArray[], const size_t nBegin, const size_t nMiddle, const size_t nEnd);
void merge_sort(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nBegin, const size_t nEnd);

int main(const int argc, const char** const argv, const char** const envp)
{
    const size_t nLength = 12;//atoi(argv[1]);

    int* nArray = (int*) malloc((uLength) * sizeof(int));
    if(!nArray) error(1);

    set_array(nArray, uLength);
    get_array(nArray, nLength);

    // merge_sort doesn't work correct
    merge_sort(nArray, 0, nLength - 1);

    get_array(nArray, nLength);

    free((void*) nArray);

    return 0;
}

void error(const unsigned uCode)
{
    switch(uCode)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("A\040segmentation\040error\040occurred.\r\n");
        break;
        default:
            printf("An\040error\040occurred.\r\n");
        break;

    }

    exit(0);
}

void* get_array(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nLength)
{
    if(!nTargetArray) error(1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
        printf("%d\040", nTargetArray[i]);
    printf("\r\n");

    return;
}

void* set_array(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nLength)
{
    if(!nTargetArray) error(1);

    printf("Enter an integer sequence[a, b, ..]: ");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
        scanf("%d", &nTargetArray[i]);

    return;
}

void merge_sort(int* nTargetArray, const size_t nBegin, const size_t nEnd)
{
    if(nBegin < nEnd)
    {
        const size_t nMiddle = nBegin + (nEnd - nBegin) / 2;

        merge_sort(nTargetArray, nBegin, nMiddle);
        merge_sort(nTargetArray, nMiddle + 1, nEnd);

        merge(nTargetArray, nBegin, nMiddle, nEnd);

    }
    return;
}

void merge(int nTargetArray[], const size_t nBegin, const size_t nMiddle, const size_t nEnd)
{
    int i, j, k;

    unsigned uLeftSize = nMiddle - nBegin + 1;
    unsigned uRightSize = nEnd - nMiddle;

    int nLeftArray[uLeftSize];
    int nRightArray[uRightSize];

    for(i = 0; i < uLeftSize; i++)
        nLeftArray[i] = nTargetArray[nBegin + i];

    for(j = 0; j < uRightSize; j++)
        nRightArray[j] = nTargetArray[nMiddle + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    while(i < uLeftSize && j < uRightSize)
    {
        if(nLeftArray[i] <= nRightArray[j])
        {
            nTargetArray[k] = nLeftArray[i];
            i++;

        } else
        {
            nTargetArray[k] = nRightArray[j];
            j++;

        }
        k++;

    } // End of while.

    // Copy the remaining elements of left array, if there are any.
    while(i < uLeftSize)
    {
        nTargetArray[k] = nLeftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;

    }

    // Copy the remaining elements of right array, if there are any.
    while(j < uRightSize)
    {
        nTargetArray[k] = nRightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;

    }
    return;
}
```

Буду невероятно признателен тому, кто объяснит, в чём заключается проблема.

Comment: Минутку, алгоритм реализован верно, а данные кривые.... может понятия отсортированной последовательности расходятся? Ваши ожидания - Ваши проблемы ©А.Аршавин

Comment: Не стоит удалять свой вопрос, если на него уже дан ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = 1;
```

исправьте на

```
k = nBegin;
```

Comment: Эту строку исправили? Отладчиком пользовались?

Comment: Ну и ну. `В этой строке нет никакой проблемы` - т.е. Вас не смущает, что нулевой элемент массива не будет заполнен? И в связи с **неправильным началом отсчёта** происходит выход за границу массива, что героически прeодолевается костылём в виде расширения массива?

Comment: Скажу больше, это был тот же алгоритм с той же реализацией, но не мой. С этим всё ещё проблема.

Comment: Ну что же подумать-то не хотите. `nBegin`

Comment: @Abraham Revic Вы знаете, что верные ответы принято помечать зеленой галочкой?